# Fourier transform of $f(z)=e^{az}e^{-e^z}$.

Tags: complex-analysis, fourier-transform, gamma-function

Problem: Let $f(z) = e^{az}e^{-e^z}$ where $a>0$. Observe that in the strip $\{x+iy:|y|<\pi\}$ the function $f(x+iy)$ is exponentially decreasing as $|x|$ tends to infinity. Prove that $$\hat{f}(\xi)= \Gamma(a+i\xi), \quad\text{for all }\xi\in\mathbb{R}.$$

---

My attempt:

$$\hat{f}(\xi) = \int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x)e^{-2\pi ix\xi}\,\mathrm{d}x = \int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{ax}e^{-e^x}e^{-2\pi ix\xi}\,\mathrm{d}x.$$
Let $u = e^x$, so $x = \log u$, and $$\hat{f}(\xi) = \int_0^\infty u^{a- 1} e^{-u}u^{-2\pi i\xi}\,\mathrm{d}u = \Gamma(a-2\pi i\xi ).$$

---

I am confused with the discrepancy and do not know whether there was a mistake in my calculation or the two expressions are actually equivalent.

Comment: Which FT definition is the person who wrote the problem using?

Comment: To add to what @mattos wrote: FT is often defined without $2\pi$

Comment: **Exercise** If $g$ is analytic in that strip and $g(x)\in\Bbb R$ for all $x\in\Bbb R$ then $g(\overline z)=\overline{g(z)}$.

Comment: @mattos The problem I was working on is from Stein & Shakarchi's Complex analysis, where the definition of Fourier transform has the $2\pi$ on the exponential.

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich Sorry but I could not figure out how this exercise is related to the problem. Would you mind illustrating it more explicitly? Thanks!

Comment: Let $f=\Gamma$.

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich Then I think I could get $\Gamma(a-2\pi i\xi) = \overline{\Gamma(a+2\pi i \xi)}$, but I am afraid that I still do not know how to proceed.

Comment: I'm working on this problem. I think this problem has several typos.